# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" when loading html page in browser

Tags: reactjs, undefined, typeerror

I have written some part of the code using react js to develop a website.

I see the event classes data missing in the web page when loading localhost/events.html page.

I am able to see the events classes data in events.html only after browsing a different page from same website. But not on first hit to that page.

Below is the stack trace found in chrome developer tools. I am facing the same issue other browsers as well.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
at EventClasses.render (Events.js:24)
at ReactCompositeComponent.js:793
at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:73)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (ReactCompositeComponent.js:792)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:819)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:359)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:255)
at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:43)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:368)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:255
```

Code for appropriate Events.js file

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import marked from 'marked'
import {createStructuredSelector} from 'reselect';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import $ from 'jquery'
import moment from 'moment'
import {analytics} from '../../../utils/trackingHelpers';
import {load_contentful} from '../actions';
import {selectEventClasses} from '../selectors';

export class EventClasses extends PureComponent {

    componentDidMount(){
        const {dispatch, load_contentful} = this.props;
        dispatch(load_contentful());
    }

    render(){
        const {events} = this.props;
        //Setting values in nextClass field
        events.map((e) => {
            e.nextClass = {};
            var sDate = new Date(e.startTime);
            e.startDateTime = sDate;
            var options = {weekday: 'short', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'};
            var sDateStr = sDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
            e.nextClass.day = sDateStr.split(', ')[0];

            var dateOptions = {year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'};
            e.nextClass.date = sDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', dateOptions);

            var eDate = new Date(e.endTime);
            var dayOptions = {year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', hc: 'h12'};
            var startTime = sDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', dayOptions);
            var endTime = eDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', dayOptions);


            var startTimeArr = startTime.split(' ');
            var endTimeArr = endTime.split(' ');
            var startTimeStr = startTimeArr[3].length==4?'0'+startTimeArr[3]:startTimeArr[3];
            var endTimeStr = endTimeArr[3].length==4?'0'+endTimeArr[3]:endTimeArr[3];
            e.nextClass.time = startTimeStr+' '+startTimeArr[4]+' - '+endTimeStr+' '+endTimeArr[4]; 
            e.nextClass.location = e.location; 
            return e;
        });
        //Sorting the events array in ascending order of startDateTime
        var key = 'startDateTime';
        events.sort(function(a, b) {
            var x = a[key] == null? "":a[key]; 
            var y = b[key] == null? "":b[key]; 
            return x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0;
        });

        return <div>
        {events.map((event, index) =>
            <div key={`events${index}`} className="event">
                    <div className="event-inner">
                        <div className="event-details">
                            <h2 className={`event-title title-icon-${event.icon}`}>
                                {event.title}
                            </h2>
                            <div className="event-meta">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Introductory Fee: ${event.fee}</li>
                                    <li>Location: {event.location}</li>
                                    <li>Instructor: {event.instructor}</li>
                                </ul>
                                {event.allClasses ? <a className="event-all-dates">See All Class Dates</a> : null}
                            </div>
                            <div className="event-description" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: marked(event.description)}}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="event-other">
                            <div className="event-other-inner">
                                <div className="event-next-class">
                                    <div className="event-next-class-inner">
                                        <h2 className="event-next-class-title">Info</h2>
                                        <div className="event-next-class-description">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>{event.nextClass.day} | {event.nextClass.date}</li>
                                                <li>{event.nextClass.time}</li>
                                                <li>Location: {event.nextClass.location}</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="event-cta">
                                    <a href={event.link} target="_blank" onClick={() => analytics('event', `Classes:click:Book This Class (${event.title} - ${event.nextClass.date}) CTA`)} className="btn btn__secondary btn__lg btn__uppercase event-cta-btn">Book This Class</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>)
        }
        </div>
    }
}

//export default Events;

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
    events: selectEventClasses()
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        dispatch,
        load_contentful
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EventClasses);
```

Comment: The `events` prop from the `createStructuredSelector({})` is undefined.

Comment: @HenrikAndersson Could you please elaborate here? Where and how do I need to define it? I am pretty new to react js

Comment: If you see const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
    events: selectEventClasses() I have already defined it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set default props

```
EventClasses.defaultProps = {
    events: []
}
```

Comment: tried this, didn't work. Getting cannot find module exception now

Comment: did you add this outside the class scope?

Comment: where do I have to add this exactly?

Comment: It worked for me when place outside the class scope!

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to pass state to selector.
2. You can check if events is define, so you will not have map on undefined.
3. Avoid all those computation on render. Render should render the componente, and not make all those calcs.